# "Find Contribution" has stopped functioning

Tags: civicontribute

Drupal 7.91
CiviCRM 5.51.1

We have lost the ability to use Find Contributions. It just shows the header & footer on that page. Everything else seems to be fine. We can see reports, contacts, events, etc. Even within Contributions we can access reports, etc. We just cannot do anything with Find Contributions.

We did an update to Civi July 15, but we have used Find Contribution since then.

I do not have any errors in the Civi or Drupal logs that seem related to when we try to access Find Contribution.

Is it safe for me to uncheck Contributions in Admin > System Settings > Components save and then re enable it?
Or any other ideas of what to look for?

Additional Info
This may or may not be the cause. Yesterday we ran out of file space on our webhost due to too many stored backups. When we ran out of allotted space, our civi scheduled jobs stopped running. I deleted the extra backups and manually triggered the scheduled jobs. It was after this was the first that we noticed we cannot access Find Contributions. But I am not sure if the Find Contributions was an issue earlier or since this.

Comment: That sounds odd. Clear cache? Maybe some corruption in the related templates_c file.

Comment: I had flushed the cache several times before posting this. I am editing my post to include some additional information that might help solve the issue

Comment: Is there process to restore templates_c file?

Comment: Just using civi will automatically recreate the necessary files.

Answer (score 2):

I checked on Extensions and saw that there was an update for Extended Reports. This was not showing a message as it normally does that there are extensions to update. But once I ran the update, Find Contributions is back. Likely no connection between Extended Reports and Find Contributions. But doing the update reset something.

Maybe if you run into a similar situation, try disabling, uninstall, and reinstall an extension and see if it fixes the issue.